# uitable view for differnet locations and uimap view for map information in one xib(same uiviewcontroller)?

Tags: ios

I want to use `uitableview` with uimap in `ios.Uitable` which display location names and uimap view which display map information. 
Is it possible to use uitable view for different locations and `uimap` view for map information in one `xib(same uiviewcontroller)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use location picker view
 https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/locationpickerview 
 
it's combination of 
MKMapView + UITableView + Parallax scrolling.